# javascript, set height as width for a div element

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to build a page, consisting of quadrats. I wasn't able to make it with css, so i tryed with javascript. My script looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var box-width = document.getElementById('foo').offsetWidth;

var element = document.getElementsByClassName('home-box');
for(var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
element[i].style.height = 'box-width';
}
</script>

</head>

<div class="body">
<div class="home-box">
<p>Lorem</p>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me, why it is not working? And I am a beginner, so maybe the mistake is very basic.

Or maybe there is a way to use CSS?

Answer (score 1):

`box-width` is not a valid identifier in JavaScript. It actually means `box minus width`, which makes no sense in the location where you use it.

I'm not exactly sure what you meant, but this snippet fixes some issues, and may lead you to a solution.

Most notable changes:

- Introduced the id `foo` in the HTML, so you can actually get that element
- Changed `box-width` to `box_width` to make it a valid JavaScript identifier
- Used the variable rather than `"box-width" as a string constant, and added the unit`'px'`.
- Added a border in CSS, so you can see that the element actually gets a height.

```js
var box_width = document.getElementById('foo').offsetWidth;

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('home-box');
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].style.height = box_width + 'px';
}
```

```css
.home-box {
   border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div id="foo" class="home-box">
    <p>Lorem</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
element[i].style.height = 'box-width';
```

With

```
element[i].style.height = box-width + "px";
```